# How does the Keyword Order in the domain name effects SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, keywords

From the Google keyword research tool, I see "chuck norris jokes" has global 246,000 searches. And again searching "jokes chuck norris" has the same search result.

But as see, order of keyword in search terms has, "hello how are you" and "how are you hello" has clearly different results.

Now instead of search term (assuming "chuck norris jokes"), I was wondering, if I had to register chucknorrisjokes.com and jokeschucknorris.com, would it effect the ranking on the search result? Or would it be the same? As we see here, both the domains has the same keywords, just in different order. How would that effect?

I hope what I am trying to say is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a branding ploy, some companies will buy similar domains just in case. Also its good to have both, just in case someone searches for the other. Just have one master domain that the subdomains point back to, like a redirect or create a landing page for each domain pointing back to the main website.

Answer (score 5):

The order of the keywords in a domain name and content does affect search results. Just Google "chuck norris jokes" and "jokes chuck norris" and you'll see the results differ especially as you move further down the results.

Comment: In the end though, worrying about this stuff is not worth the effort. Who wants a (grammatically) nonsensical domain name like jokeschucknorris?

Answer (score 1):

What does SEO have to do with picking a domain name? Instead of optimizing for some careless cold calculating machine algorithm, optimize first and foremost for the actual target audience of your site - that is humans.

It just so happens that most of the "SEO tricks" are actually modeled in such a way that also improve your human target audience experience and help them to consume you content. Which should be ultimately the goal of any web site.

SEO can only give you so much edge. If the content is not good enough or is difficult/confusing to consume, no amount of SEO will help your site.